# How to get all IP address in these ranges from this format?

Tags: c#, ip-address

How would one work out all the IP addresses in this range from this format?

```
213.159.160.0-213.159.191.255
84.44.115.72-84.44.115.79
```

I've found examples of `84.44.115.1/23` format but none in the format above.

Comment: Please show us, what you've tried so far.

Comment: One simple way could be to convert the upper and lower bound to integer representation. All natural number in between are your ip addresses then.

Comment: Do just want a list of IP addresse between the two values or do you want subnetting?

Comment: I don't normally answer "give me code" questions because no effort has been displayed on your part, but I figured I'd like to do it for fun anyway, so I've answered. In future, I recommend showing what you have tried first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this?:

```
public static IPAddress[] GetAddresses(string rangeString)
{
    var match = Regex.Match(rangeString, @"(?<ip1>\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})-(?<ip2>\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})");
    if (!match.Success || !IPAddress.TryParse(match.Groups["ip1"].Value, out IPAddress ip1) || !IPAddress.TryParse(match.Groups["ip2"].Value, out IPAddress ip2))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("Range invalid.");
    }
    return GetAddresses(ip1, ip2);
}

public static IPAddress[] GetAddresses(IPAddress startAddress, IPAddress endAddress)
{
    var startNumber = IPToNumber(startAddress);
    var endNumber = IPToNumber(endAddress);

    var addresses = new List<IPAddress>();
    for (uint i = startNumber; i <= endNumber; ++i)
    {
        addresses.Add(NumberToIP(i));
    }
    return addresses.ToArray();
}

private static UInt32 IPToNumber(IPAddress ip)
{
    var bytes = ip.GetAddressBytes();
    UInt32 result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; ++i)
    {
        result *= 255;
        result += bytes[i];
    }
    return result;
}

private static IPAddress NumberToIP(UInt32 number)
{
    var bytes = new Stack<byte>(4);
    while (number > 0)
    {
        bytes.Push((byte)(number % 255));
        number /= 255;
    }
    return new IPAddress(bytes.ToArray());
}
```

It converts the start and address to `UInt32` values, and loops through numerically, converting the index back into an IPAddress object.

I wasn't sure if you needed to actually to parse a range string, so I've added it as a separate method at the top. If you do need it, you can roll the methods into one, otherwise feel free to disregard it.

[Try it online](http://rextester.com/EDOE4295)